# Telegram Bot how to send HTML file directly?

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, telegraf

I created a game using HTML, now I am trying to import it in my js file, and send to user.

This is my code so far

```
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf')
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
const test = require('./index.html');

bot.hears('?', ctx => {
//   console.log(ctx.from)
  let msg = `Spin the wheel`;
  ctx.deleteMessage();
  bot.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, msg, {
      reply_markup: {
          inline_keyboard: [
              [{
                      text: "SPIN",
                      callback_data: 'wheeloffortune'
                  }
              ],
          ]
      }
  })
})


bot.action('wheeloffortune', ctx => {
    bot.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, test, {parse_mode: 'HTML'});
})
```

but I am getting this error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: You need to have a "transpile" step, to convert the HTML into JavaScript. Are you using something like webpack?

Comment: any hints on how to do that?? like what library i can use to do that

Comment: but creating my telegram bot does not require webpack

Comment: It will if you wish to include HTML like this.

Comment: I will try and update here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned on Telegram BOT API's [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#html-style), `parse_mode` of type `html` only supports a few tags. Therefore, you can't send your game's html file to the chat for the user with `parse_mode` set to `html`.

Here's what the docs say:

To use this mode, pass HTML in the parse_mode field. The following tags are currently supported:

```
<b>bold</b>, <strong>bold</strong>
<i>italic</i>, <em>italic</em>
<u>underline</u>, <ins>underline</ins>
<s>strikethrough</s>, <strike>strikethrough</strike>, <del>strikethrough</del>
<span class="tg-spoiler">spoiler</span>, <tg-spoiler>spoiler</tg-spoiler>
<b>bold <i>italic bold <s>italic bold strikethrough <span class="tg-spoiler">italic bold strikethrough spoiler</span></s> <u>underline italic bold</u></i> bold</b>
<a href="http://www.example.com/">inline URL</a>
<a href="tg://user?id=123456789">inline mention of a user</a>
<code>inline fixed-width code</code>
<pre>pre-formatted fixed-width code block</pre>
<pre><code class="language-python">pre-formatted fixed-width code block written in the Python programming language</code></pre>
```

- Only the tags mentioned above are currently supported.
- All <, > and & symbols that are not a part of a tag or an HTML entity must be replaced with the corresponding HTML entities (< with <, > with > and & with &).
- All numerical HTML entities are supported.
- The API currently supports only the following named HTML entities: <, >, & and ".
- Use nested pre and code tags, to define programming language for pre entity.
- Programming language can't be specified for standalone code tags.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer, I have switch my method